# How does ModelCheckpoint work? I am getting spurious results when re evaluating a model saved by model checkpoint

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, callback, image-classification

For training a multi-class classification model, I used the model checkpoint to save a model with the best validation accuracy during training. And according to the verbose output from the model checkpoint, that appears to be occurring correctly. However, when a re load the best saved model, and test it on the same validation data, the results are quite lower than they should be.

This is the initialization of the callback.

```
callbacks = [keras.callbacks.ModelCheckpoint("model_adam_effnet_5.h5", monitor="val_accuracy", save_best_only=True, mode="max", verbose=1),
             ]
```

[[image: This is the validation accuracy and output of the callback during training.1]

This is the validation accuracy and output of the callback during training.

However when I reload this model and evaluate it again on the validation set, I get a much lower validation accuracy.

[image]

This shouldn't occur if the model that was saved is representative of what it was during training.

When I evaluate the model which was fit on the validation data, I get the same validation accuracy as the one on the last epoch during training.

Model validation accuracy during training and last epoch.

[image]

Model validation accuracy when re-evaluating.

[image]

This should be the same for the model saved by the model checkpoint, can anyone please explain to me the exact working, or if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: Please provide minimal reproducible code to replicate the issue or please have a look on this [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/save_and_load#checkpoint_callback_usage) for `ModelCheckpoint` functionality and compare it with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I know its a bit late for an answer but i will leave it right here in case someone needs an answer. One of the possible solutions to this is to increase your batch size. I could decrease the difference increasing my batch size, but still there is a difference. It is possible that BatchNorm layer is responsible for this problem. It can be good to check it out here : https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6977